# Reset counter every second

Tags: android, timer, bluetooth

I am trying to reset a counter that runs on a Bluetooth receive thread. I have 4 data bytes in each packet being sent by a BT transmitter. Packet time is 300 ms. The receive data gets out of sequence for an unknown reason after some time so I thought I could add a timer to reset the counter between packets to ensure valid data. According to the blogs I have read there is no built in timeouts so I assume someone has created one.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[20];    // Start new packetbyte
        Log.d(TAG,  " Counter  " + counter);
        mmInStream.read(packetBytes);         // Read Bluetooth socket 
        b [counter]= packetBytes[0];          // Save each byte into B
        counter++;
        if(counter == 4){                     // After 4 bytes DO this
            Log.d(TAG, " Done  ");  
            counter=0;                        // Reset counter
            h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, counter, -1, b).sendToTarget();    // Send to message queue Handler   
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the code to count the data. I am trying to reset the counter.

Comment: So you mean the counter still increment ? and you want to reset it.? Sorry I have to ask,

Comment: Sorry I was not clear on the reset. The counter increments each time a byte is received. When counter reaches 4 then the packet is finished.  If there is a error in the receive and I miss a byte I need to reset counter before a new packet starts. If a reset triggers 1 each second I think this will work. I could also reset the timer to start on each byte received to ensure the counter is not reset during a packet receive.

Comment: How about initializing your counter variable inside the while loop?